# MailCore2 with Gmail and OAuth2 sends ONLY with full access scope i.e. https://mail.google.com

Tags: objective-c, gmail-api, mailcore2

My app sends emails via Gmail using Mailcore2. I use OAuth2 authentication for that too. It works great if FULL access scope selected: `https://mail.google.com`

However, Google proposed to use other scopes (send). I am trying out `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send` and/or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose`

Mailcore2 does not send with these scopes returning:

`MCOSMTPResponseCodeKey=535, NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to authenticate with the current session's credentials., MCOSMTPResponseKey=5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.`

Does MailCore2 need full access scope?
Any workarounds?

here is my sending with MailCore2 code that works only with FULL scope:

```
MCOSMTPSession *smtpSession = [[MCOSMTPSession alloc] init];
smtpSession.hostname = @"smtp.gmail.com";
smtpSession.port = 465;

[smtpSession setAuthType:MCOAuthTypeXOAuth2];
[smtpSession setOAuth2Token:delAuthAccessToken];//from oauth2
[smtpSession setUsername:delAuthUserEmail];

smtpSession.authType =MCOAuthTypeXOAuth2;
smtpSession.connectionType=MCOConnectionTypeTLS;

MCOMessageBuilder *builder = [[MCOMessageBuilder alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *to = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[to addObject:[MCOAddress addressWithDisplayName:delSendName mailbox:delSendEmail]];
MCOAddress *from = [MCOAddress addressWithDisplayName:delAuthUserEmail mailbox:delAuthUserEmail];

[[builder header] setFrom:from];
[[builder header] setTo:to];
[[builder header] setSubject:@"Sent By MyApp"];
[builder setTextBody:delMessage];
NSData * rfc822Data = [builder data];

MCOSMTPSendOperation *sendOperation =[smtpSession sendOperationWithData:rfc822Data];

[sendOperation start:^(NSError *error) {
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"Error sending email: %@", error);

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Message sent sucessfully.");
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, answering my own question cause no workarounds can be implemented i.e. MailCore requires full access to GMail account, Google won't allow that.

I ended up switching to HTTP POST/GET requests instead of using Mailcore.
Here is a link to my other answer that shows an example how to send and receive emails  [send/receive email with http post in ObjC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42777107/send-email-in-gmail-api-objective-c/57209818#57209818)

Comment: Exactly what I needed to hear, thanks. So, we can't do it with mailcore. We are going to implement REST API for Gmail in our application which only needs read access to Gmail

Answer (score 0):

The Gmail scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send` is perfect for sending emails with the Gmail API from your own email address. However, if you are planning to send email from an alias, you'd need to add a restricted scope to your project.

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic`

The `gmail.settings.basic` scope lets you send emails from aliases connected to the Gmail account of the authenticated user.

Comment: I tried all scopes including the one you suggested - getting the same error, only full access scope works. I am using Mailcore2 to send/receive.